# iOS software keyboard closing when switching between inputs in React app

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, keyboard, uikeyboard

I am building a React app and I have a form with multiple input fields.  As I am attempting to switch between the inputs on mobile the software keyboard closes and I have to tap on the input again.

Is this due to a re-render by React? I also have to hit the submit button twice to submit.  Once to close the software keyboard and again to submit the form.

It appears to be iOS exclusive as my coworker with an Android phone has a persistent software keyboard when switching between input fields.

shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: Please paste your code.